# Achartengine drawing from, right to left

Tags: android, achartengine

Hi I´m using achartengine using dates in the x axis but when I insert data  the drawing begins from right to left , any tip to resolve this behaviour ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by setting a mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-1); and a
            mRenderer.setXAxisMax(10); with this the graph drawing was perfect .